# How to pass selected value of one list's ID column to another list's column?

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer

I have two list LatestJobList and AppliedUserInformation.
In first list there are latest jobs are posted along with ID column which is inbuilt in list.
what i want is when user clicks on particular job than that selected ID should enter in AppliedUserInformation list. I have created JobID Column in AppliedUserInformation list which is lookup column. but i don't want it in drop-down list. it should automatically added. 
I have created one form in sharepoint designer for User detail entry like name last name etc.... when he will click on submit button all the details will save in AppliedUserInformation List but JobID is not enteres for that particular job

Ho do i do that????

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to achieve that using Event Receivers. 
On the "OnItemAdded" and "OnItemUpdated" events on the AppliedUserInformation List, you can update the related item in the other list.

Event Receivers related links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728093.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398052.aspx

Comment: will this work for Apply Link's click event????